# How to Move a Dynamically Created folder into another folder?

Tags: cmd

I am trying to moving generated folders in which the date is dynamic for example:

`results_20190821T43302`.

Which would reside in a path as such:

`C:\Test\results_20190821T43302`

The folder "items" in which I want to move them too is: `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\items\`

**I have tried:**

`move C:\Test\results_*  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\items\`

However it is returning: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: On Microsoft Windows, a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) is used for a directory path separator. `move C:\Test\results_* C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Items`

Comment: @lit, Updated Syntax. I confirm I did user proper Windows Backslash but still  getting: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`move` command](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html) does not accept [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) against directories. But you can use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve wildcards, like this:

```cmd
for /D %I in ("C:\Test\results_*") do @move "%~I" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\items\"
```

Since you have got a trailing backslash `\` at the source directory, the source directory is moved *into* the destination directory, which must exist. If you want to move the *contents* of the source directory, remove the trailing `\` from the destination directory and ensure this does *not* exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, however I found
`for /D %%G in ("C:\Test\results_*") do move "%%~G"    "%UserProfile%\Desktop\items\"`  work for me.